# Can i use nested_form_for from the show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-form-for

```
<%= @movie.link_to_add "Add Trailers", :trailers %>
<%= @movie.fields_for :trailers do |trailer| %>
<%= trailer.text_field :name, :placeholder =>"enter the keyword " %>
<%= trailer.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
<% end %>'
```

i am using imdb-party gem to fetch the records from imdb database . 
now i need to add trailers to the movies. for which i am using simple nested_form_for
i want to add multiple trailers to the database . 
so basically i want a link on my show movie page saying "Add Trailers", once i click on this a nested form should appear with a text_field , in which i want to add the url and submit .

plss help ..! i am newbie on rails

this is something i am trying to do , this is written on the show page ..not on the form

this returns me an error 
undefined method `link_to_add' for #

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this? I'm having a similar problem...